# Beginner stats: Predict binary outcome of set of numbers given history (Logistic regression)

Tags: python, logistic-regression, statsmodels

I apologize in advance for the simplicity of this question. I have no background in stats and am getting lost in the complexity of it all.

If I have a couple thousand numbers all with a binary outcome

```
number,outcome
14,0
27,1
88,1
04,0
42,1
```

How do I predict future numbers ? for example:

```
82
45
02
```

Or is this going to be inaccurate due to there only being a single variable ? All the examples I have seen use multiple variables.

I have been digging through statsmodels and went through this great tutorial: http://blog.yhathq.com/posts/logistic-regression-and-python.html. And through that I've made this:

```
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.api as sm

df = pd.read_csv("binary.csv")
df.columns = ["number", "outcome"]
data = df[['number', 'outcome']]
train_cols = data.columns[0]
logit = sm.Logit(data['outcome'], data[train_cols])
result = logit.fit()
print result.summary()
```

But that seems to be analyzing the weight of current numbers, how would you predict new ones ? Am I even going about this the right way ?

Comment: my guess is that you will also need to add a constant, which is not added automatically except when using the formula interface.

Comment: Got it, anything else I might need ?

Comment: I think not. As reminder: the array of explanatory variables in the call to `predict` has to match the structure of the `exog` explanatory variables in the model, i.e. also include a constant. Using formulas will be easier, it automatically adds a constant, and will do the same transformation in the call to `predict`. However, it will have avoidable overhead that might become relevant in repeated calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result of the fit should have a method `predict()`. That is what you need to use to predict future values, for example:

```
result = sm.Logit(outcomes, values).fit()
result.predict([82,45,2])
```

Comment: I knew I was close, so simple. Thanks.